# Mod Rewrite Wamp

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

Hi I have a site configured with Mod rewrite and it is working as expected on the server however when I try to create a local version of the site with wamp on windows it doesn't work.  I think something must be different with my local environment.

I have enabled the rewrite module and confirmed its loaded with phpinfo()

Can anyone help me troubleshoot further.  Normally it enables me to access index.php with http://domainname/index

Many Thanks in advance

```
    # Apache Rewrite Rules 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    DirectoryIndex index

   # Add trailing slash to url 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$ 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

    # Remove .php-extension from url 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php
```